# In Android O, how to get any action on Success call back intent while pinning widget shortcut programmatically?

Tags: android

I am trying the API given in android O for pinning widget shortcut as given in

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Pinning

The sample code given is:

```
AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager = context.getSystemService(AppWidgetManager.class);
ComponentName myProvider = new ComponentName(context, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);

if (mAppWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported()) {
    // Create the PendingIntent object only if your app needs to be notified
    // that the user allowed the widget to be pinned. Note that, if the pinning
    // operation fails, your app isn't notified.
    Intent pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = new Intent( ... );

    // Configure the intent so that your app's broadcast receiver gets
    // the callback successfully. This callback receives the ID of the
    // newly-pinned widget (EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID).
    PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.createBroadcast(context, 0,
            pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent);

    mAppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null, successCallback);
}
```

In the above, if I am trying to get any activity through success Callback intent i.e the activity should open just after pinning shortcut, I am not getting it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

I have ran into this as well. Intent you are passing in should be for your implementation of BroadcastReceiver.

```
val callbackIntent = Intent(context, DemoWidgetPinnedReceiver::class.java)
val successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
       context, 0, callbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(provider, null, successCallback)
```

After widget is added successfully, you will get EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID in the onReceive method of your BroadcastReceiver, and you can then save the ID. You shouldn't need to launch configuration activity after widget is pinned, as you can pass any values you want to save for the widget to into the callback intent.

I have written a blog post about this and also created a demo app, hope this helps!
https://medium.com/wearebase/android-oreo-widget-pinning-in-kotlin-398d529eab28
https://github.com/sigute/WidgetsDemo