# Passing value to widget receiver

Tags: android, kotlin, glance-appwidget

I'm currently working with a widget Android app using Kotlin 1.9.10 and Glance 1.0.0. I want to pin widget to home screen programmatically. I can get the widget id in onReceive fun but I want to pass more value into that.

I'm using this piece of code to pin my widget to home screen.

```
val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
val myProvider = ComponentName(context, MyWidgetReceiver::class.java)

val pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

val successCallback = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 0,
        pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
    
appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null, successCallback)
```

And in my Receiver, I override onReceive fun to get the Widget ID which have just been pinned to home screen.

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        if (intent.action == AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE) {
            val extras = intent.extras
            val widgetId = extras?.getIntArray(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS)?.firstOrNull() ?: -1
        }
    }
```

But the problem is I want to pass one more value so that I can save it to the local storage as map, using widget id as key.
How can I do that, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

2 thousand years later, I found this answer. This solution is the best and it work well on my case.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47352244/22885025

Shortly: Create a BroadcastReceiver (remember to declare it in manifest). Then the success callback will use PendingIntent getBroadcast, which is our receiver

```
val pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = Intent(context, PinnedWidgetReceiver::class.java)
    pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent.putExtras(bundleOf("key" to "value"))

    val successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, 0,
        pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )

    appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null, successCallback)
```

If the widget is pinned successfully, it will send a broadcast, which contain `widgetId` as extras (and our value, too). In `onReceive` of our broadcast receiver (in my case is PinnedWidgetReceiver), we can do the stuff we want.

```
class PinnedWidgetReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent == null || context == null) return

        val widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1)
        val widgetName = intent.getStringExtra("key") ?: "default value"
        //do the stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [`requestPinAppWidget`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager#requestPinAppWidget(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) documentation I've found that you can pass a `Bundle` as a parameter and you are passing `null`.

So you should change this

```
appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null, successCallback)
```

To this

```
val extras = Bundle().apply {
    putString("key", "value")
}
appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null, successCallback)
```

In case you want to do it after it, you should use [`updateAppWidgetOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager#updateAppWidgetOptions(int,%20android.os.Bundle)) and send also a `Bundle` and override the `onUpdate` method and getting the values using

```
val extras = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId)
val value = extras.getString("key")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. But according to the document, the extras parameter is pass to the launcher, not the receiver
`extras – In not null, this is passed to the launcher app. For eg EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PREVIEW can be used for a custom preview.`. I've tried to pass the value I want but the Log at onReceive only has appWidgetId

Comment: Can you check this post?
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html I guess updateAppWidget is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank @skizo, but in my case, I want to pass my value to the receive because I want to get the widgetId and my value at the same time. When I call `requestPinAppWidget`, I have my value but don't have the widgetId. In onReceive fun, I have widgetId but don't have my value.

Comment: @DangNguyenHoang can you save it in a variable? First get the widgetId then when you update check if the widgetId is not null then do stuff?

Comment: Thank you so much, I've found some great solution that work well for me. I've just posted the answer below.